# Disabling antialiasing for Proggy Clean fonts in GNOME shell 3.10.4

Tags: gnome, fonts

Cross-post from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1163167/disabling-antialiasing-for-proggy-clean-fonts-in-gnome-shell-3-10-4).

---

I've already followed the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32727/how-do-i-turn-off-font-pixel-antialiasing-only-in-terminal), and I have

```
$ ls ~/.fonts
FSEX300.ttf                 LucidaSansDemiBold.ttf
LucidaBrightDemiBold.ttf    LucidaSansRegular.ttf
LucidaBrightDemiItalic.ttf  LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf
LucidaBrightItalic.ttf      LucidaTypewriterRegular.ttf
LucidaBrightRegular.ttf     ProggyCleanTT.ttf
```

and in `~/.fonts.conf` I have

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  <dir>~/.fonts</dir>
  <match target="pattern">
    <test name="family">
      <string>ProggyCleanTT</string>
    </test>
    <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
      <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

After running `fc-cache ~/.fonts`, nothing happens (restarting doesn't work either) - Proggy Clean is still antialiased in gnome-terminal.

What's wrong with my config file?

Comment: Have you checked elsewhere besides gnome-terminal, may be it interferes with the rendering? Some workarounds: 1) there is pcf version of the font available 2) in Konsole antialiasing can be disabled in profile settings